# How Bearer token is working in token based authentication using Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: ajax, authentication, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I tried token based authentication same like this [website link](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/token-based-authentication-in-aspnet-web-api).

It is working fine for me. But I have 2 questions

> 1. After I add the below code, it's checking for every request from the client and validate the user. If it success, it will return some data, if not, it will show **unauthorize**.
>
>    But the problem is, After I logged in(**http://localhost:49501/Home**), it shows **success** only on **same browser tab**(**http://localhost:49501/Home/Data**).
>
>    But After I logged in(Tab1) and I tried to visit same url (**http://localhost:49501/Home/Data**) but on another tab(tab2) with same chrome browser, it is showing **unauthorize error**

**Data.cshtml**

```
 var  authHeaders = {};
 authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken');

 $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:49501/api/values",
     type: "GET",
     headers: authHeaders,
     success: function (response) {
         console.log('Success');
     }
 });
```

> 2. Is it really secure to send the token using AJAX? Because all the codes are appearing on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is one issue in your code I can see in line:

   `authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken');`

`sessionStorage.setItem` method has **two mandatory parameters** & give error without it, there must be some js error below in developer console when this execute. Correct usage for sessionStorage is :

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

2. To answer your second question **"Is it really secure to send the token using AJAX? Because all the codes are appearing on the client side."**

The idea is to generate some accessToken on server using user credentials which is valid for limited time. Advantage is you can authorize subsequent request using authToken till it is valid and you need not to store real username & password for authorizing each request. Also by adding some mechanism to refresh security token if session is active for longer period you can prevent user logout/reauthorization request.

To clear security concern, real user credentials are not saved & auth token have limited time validity. for example if you security token has validity of 30 min, if user left machine after 30 min of inactive session further this token can't be used.

Also you can regenerate security token every few minutes in session & update on session storage in background for further security. Also saving them on local machine is not so unsecure in case machine is private but for public machine also we can make sure we clear any session storage on logout/time-out, if left as it is then also token expires after some time.

Hope it helps

Comment: If time expiry is for 10 hours, what if some one copy the token and run it on another machiner?, Are they still able to login?

Comment: Security token is not for login, it is generated after successful login on server & then used for subsequent request authorization. Data in request over https is also encrypted. If someone can track your network to get security token then he won't know parameters are used for what purpose or what is valid data since data is encrypted. If you are using http then it can be misused easily

Comment: If you are on secured network or machine then this is highly unlike but for public machine on unsecured network with website sending data on http is real deal breaker